# How can a one-man team create game audio?

Tags: sound, audio, sound-effects

I am basically a 14 years game programmer.
I am using Unreal Engine 4.

I can't make a game without 3D models.
So , I started to learn how to draw (for reference images) and how to make some 3D models.
I am using Corel Painter and Blender.

I can't make a game without audio.
This is a much larger problem than the models' one.
There aren't high quality (or even low quality) tutorials that can teach you "How to make music for your game" or "How to make sound effects for your game"

I made a topic on Unity forums and they suggested to me to hire someone who can create the audio for me but I really want to make everything myself as the game I'm working on will not be published, it's just a 'showcase' for my programming 'skills'.

So, I need a program and maybe a MIDI controller that is user friendly like Ableton Push, for example, that I can use to create sound effects for my game like explosions, fire, engines' sound, ... etc. The Music isn't a much of a problem as I can use something like MAGIX Music Maker as it has user friendly interface and can create some really good music.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should check out the stack exchange for [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). I'm sure they'll have some great programs for you over there.

Comment: You can probably get away without much hardware and just look into software. Granted, things like MIDI keyboards make things easier but aren't strictly necessary. You can also pretty easily mix existing sounds with something like Audacity -- for example, check out some film sound libraries for a starting place (e.g. http://triune-store.myshopify.com/collections/sound-effects). You can make just about any sound from a few basics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking how to compose music.

Answer (score 2):

Creating sound effects is a fairly simple task as long as you have a fairly decent microphone. I'd recommend watching the ["Art of Noise" part of The Making of Fallout 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lr5olzm9jXg&feature=youtu.be&t=1790) as well as [this video by the guy making effects for Project Zomboid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zx0jkJYgiE), showing some more extreme ways of creating **very gruesome** effects.

If you listen closely, most effects are made from simple everyday objects, so the barrier of entry isn't too high.

Answer (score -1):

I know a game team who used free audio music; I'm not sure what was the name of the site, but the idea was that you had to say where the music came from in the credits.

As for the sounds, you can find free audio effects online. Or you can learn the basis of a software like audacity and create sounds using your imagination (and use audacity to achieve what you need). I remember some sounds in a game I worked on are originating from hmm, my mouth, or a tap of a spoon on my work book.

Music composition is really not an activity you should invest time in, but learning how to modify and tweak sounds in a free sound manipulation program like audacity is a skill I would say is a good "rope to your bow".

P.S. If you really need precise music for your game, I'd suggest you try and partner with a free/cheap music composer and get something exactly suited for your needs.

Comment: Thnx for the reply but ... I don't want to use free sounds because of 2 reasons, No.1 is I don't want to mention anyone in the credits not in the team (and in this case anyone but me), No.2 is You know it's free! You can't persuade me that free sounds will sound like premium ones. I don't also want to buy sounds because maybe it will not fit my game perfectly as I want. I like to do things myself even if they are difficult to begin with. http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/software-for-creating-game-sound-effects?noredirect=1#comment30357_20701

Comment: +1 to free or pay sound packs. BTW you don't need to credit all free sounds, check the license of where you get them.

Comment: My piece of advice: don't re-code the wheel and don't create artificial barriers. It's a noble goal to do everything by yourself, but in the real world, no employer will see this as an epic feat. In the real world, can you ship a game? If so, for how much? Also, Chuck Norris programmers are good for small companies. As soon as a company grows, you won't have a choice: you'll have to specialize. Ask yourself: what do you want to do as a career? _EVERYTHING!_ does not work, you won't have time to have a life.

Comment: Oh, and "I can do it all by myself!" in an interview tends to be frown upon: "Why? Are you not able to work in a team and with others?"

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt OK I can work in a team but the game I'm making will be just something like a "showcase" for my programming "skills" and also having experience in all aspects of creating a game will speed up the workflow. I am just a 14 years old programmer right now with no team and I have enough time to learn some new things. You understand me ?

Comment: @AlanWolfe I don't want to use any sounds that I didn't create myself simply

Comment: @AdhamT I get it. As a tip: in the long term, you'll have to specialize :). As for what software to use, unfortunately, we don't do this here. For music production, I would suggest you might want to dissociate your searches from game development to increase your chances to find something more suited for your needs.

Comment: +1 to all the above about specialization, focus, teamwork etc. Just wanted to also mention, if you like the idea of audio programming, you might look into procedural synthesis of your sounds and music.  Might be fun and give your game a unique sound (: